# Convert integer value to date in C

Tags: c, time

I have a 64-bit integer value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC), namely 1183042181.

How do I print it out in the format MM/DD/YYYY?

What if I am on a 32 bit system, and have to read the integer in from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C's  library contains the strftime function, which will format a struct tm using a specified format string. From there, of course, you can print it. So:

- Convert your FILETIME to seconds since 1601 by dividing by 10,000,000.
- Convert to a standard UNIX timestamp by subtracting the number of seconds between 1601-01-01 and 1970-01-01.
- Use localtime() to convert that to a struct tm.
- Use strftime() to get a formatted string.
- Print it.
- Write a function to do all of this so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: how can i subtract 5329584000 from a number on 32bit since this #is larger than 32bits

Comment: Even on 32-bit architectures, C has support for 64-bit integers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Integral_types As noted, look at the limits.h on your system. actually, just do some tests: sizeof(unsigned long long). Or you can try to something fancy like create a struct with a 64-bit integer, eg: struct {unsigned int foo:64}, though the implementation of that will vary.

Answer (score 2):

Read the MSDN section:

> **Remarks**
>
> To convert a FILETIME structure into a
>   time that is easy to display to a
>   user, use the [FileTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724280%28VS.85%29.aspx)
>   function.

Comment: isn't this specific to windows?

Comment: I assumed you meant the Windows data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Put the time into a `struct tm` and call `strftime()`.

It's all declared in [<time.h>](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.h.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this routine to convert your 64 bit value to time_t structure

```
time_t FileTimeToUnixTime(FILETIME& ft)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER li;
    assert(sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER) == sizeof(FILETIME));
    memcpy(&li, &ft, sizeof(FILETIME));
    li.QuadPart -= 116444736000000000;
    li.QuadPart /= 10000000;
    return (time_t)(li.LowPart);
}
```

Certainly this will only work if your FILETIME is really in time_t range. I suppose you know what to do with resulting time_t.

32 bit system won't prevent you from reading 64 bit as a binary value. If you prefer scanf you can use "%llu" format.